# Why do some function calls fail to work without a type application?

Tags: haskell

I am having trouble understanding how type applications work. Why can `sing` in `refuteRefuteKnockable` be used without a type application when the call to `sing` in `knockableOrOpened` will fail to type check without a type application?

```
 refuteRefuteKnockable :: SingI s => Refuted (Refuted (Knockable s)) -> Knockable s
 refuteRefuteKnockable rrK =
   case isKnockable $ sing of
     Proved k -> k
     Disproved rK -> absurd $ rrK rK

 knockableOrOpened :: forall s. SingI s => Or Knockable ((:~:) Opened) s
 knockableOrOpened =
   case sing @s of
     SOpened -> OrRight $ Refl
     SClosed -> OrLeft KnockClosed
     SLocked -> OrLeft KnockLocked
```

I am working from the following codebase: https://github.com/mstksg/inCode/blob/master/code-samples/singletons/Door3.hs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Type inference is the cause. This type contains `s` ...

```
refuteRefuteKnockable :: SingI s => Refuted (Refuted (Knockable s)) -> Knockable s
                                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So, this

```
 refuteRefuteKnockable rrK =
   case isKnockable $ sing of
     Proved k -> k
                ^^^
```

must have type `Knockable s`. Hence, the type of `Proved k` is inferred, probably containing `s` as well. That is the same type of `isKnockable $ sing`, from which we infer what type should be applied to `sing` (exploiting the signature of `isKnockable`). GHC does all of this for us.

In the latter example, we can't perform the same reasoning.

```
case sing of
     SOpened -> OrRight $ Refl
     SClosed -> OrLeft KnockClosed
     SLocked -> OrLeft KnockLocked
```

is ambiguous because, even if the three branches must return a known type, we can still call `sing` on a different type then `s` and make everything typecheck. Since there isn't a *unique* `s`, inference can not work.

Note that above I had to guess a few things. If you shared the definitions of your types, we could be more accurate. (I.e., where is `SOpened` defined? What about `Knockable`, etc.?)